# Server for Client/Server Application

Tags: asp.net, desktop, application

I have developed one `Client/Server application`. Now I am wondering that if I want to upload that application on a server, then which server will be useful here? And what configuration do I need to implement that application on server?

As my application will be used through the `internet`, I need to upload that application on a server but don't know what kind of server is needed.

Comment: a `Desktop application` cannot work over the internet. only `Web applications` can. what language did you develop the program in?

Comment: thanks for your reply. But, For your information Skype,TeamViewer, or Any Messenger application are desktop application which requires internet connection to connect with its server application what I want.I have created an server application which will be connected to other client application. client application will be installed in customer's PC and server application will be installed on server PC which is fully featured and Windows Server installed. I need an IP address where my application is installed so, i connect my client application through the server `IP address` over the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you developed a `Server/Client` application, not a `desktop application`.

You already detailed your answer, you need a windows server (if your server application is running on windows), most of the chances you will need a Dedicated server (Shared hosting does not allow custom applications to be run) or a Virtual Private Server (VPS) with at least one ip.

It is unclear what you are asking for,
The server configuration will vary depending on the amount of clients you will have.
I guess for start (if you dont have many clients) you will need the bare minimum.

some links:

[GoDaddy Virtual Private Servers](http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/vps-hosting.aspx)

[GoDaddy Dedicated Servers](http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/dedicated-servers.aspx)

For more information about selecting the type of hosting you need,
Please read [https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements) post.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the difference between VPS and Dedicated Servers??

Comment: i have added a link to a good post containing the information you need.